# Desktop based BPMN libraries for graphing.?

Tags: graphics, bpmn

Free or non-free both will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yaoqjang](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bpmn/)

[jbpm 5](http://www.jboss.org/jbpm)

http://www.bonitasoft.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yaoqiang BPMN Editor http://bpmn.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try roubroo.com. I believe they have a powerful tool & guys try their best to help you.
Thanks
Nitin